# How to convert the current date to digit format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I am getting the new date like this:

```
getCalender: function () {

            var monthNames = [
                "January", "February", "March", 
                "April", "May", "June", "July",  
                "August", "September", "October",
                "November", "December"
            ];

            var date = new Date();
            var day = date.getDate();
            var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
            var year = date.getFullYear();

            return (day + '-' + monthNames[monthIndex] + '-' + year);

        },
```

my above method returns the date format like "day" month name from array and the year.

But the back-end people requires the date format like this:

```
"IssueDate": "/Date(1407445200000+0300)/",
```

how to convert the date format to match this?
Any one help me?

Answer (score 2):

I tried this, it works fine for me:

```
var date1 = new Date();
var n = date1.getTimezoneOffset();

console.log( '/Date(' + (+date1) + n +')/' );
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Was this very different to what I answered? :)

Comment: Nope. this is just a 2 number of lines(simplified), the result are same.

Answer (score 0):

Try using getTime() in jquery as below -

```
var date = new Date();

var time = date.getTime(); //1447995963967
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
var dt = new Date(myDate);
var newDate = new Date(Date.UTC(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate(), dt.getHours(), dt.getMinutes(), dt.getSeconds(), dt.getMilliseconds()));
return '/Date(' + newDate.getTime() + ')/';
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/servux2q/)**

If you want to add the offset time then simply do

```
var dt = new Date();
var newDate = new Date(Date.UTC(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate(), dt.getHours(), dt.getMinutes(), dt.getSeconds(), dt.getMilliseconds()));
return '/Date(' + newDate.getTime()  +  newDate.getTimezoneOffset() +')/' ;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/servux2q/3/)**

Comment: But the GMT value is missing in the alert